# What does the symbol $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}$ mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What does the symbol $\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}$ mean? mean? For example some write : $"$The Inequality is then equivalent to $$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}a^2+2\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{a}\ge9"$$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means you add up over the variables in play. For example, if the original expression had $a, b, c, d$, you'd add up over those, e.g., $\sum_{cyc} a^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$.

More interesting is when you have expressions such as $\sum_{cyc} ab$ which  in the context of a problem with $a,b,c,d$ would generally mean

$$ \sum_{cyc} ab = ab + bc + cd + da$$

I'm not sure if this convention is set in stone, but it's a useful shorthand. Be sure to evaluate it in context.

Comment: The variables in play with my inequality are $a,b,c$, so $$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}a^2+2\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt{a}\ge9\iff a^2+b^2+c^2+2\sqrt a+2\sqrt b+2\sqrt c\geq9$$

Comment: Is it right Simon?

Comment: Looks reasonable. Just double check it in the context of the problem to make sure it really does make sense.

Comment: ok thanks for your help

Comment: but does the cyc stand for anything?

Comment: @user71207 I know this is kinda late, and you probably already figured it out, but it stands for cyclic. Since you are adding up on the cyclic permutations of the variables