# What are the possible solutions of $x+y+ {1\over x}+{1\over y}+4=2 (\sqrt {2x+1}+\sqrt {2y+1})$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I encountered a question in an exam in which we had:

> Find all possible solutions of the equation $$x+y+ {1\over x}+{1\over y}+4=2 (\sqrt {2x+1}+\sqrt {2y+1}) $$ where $x $ and $y$ are real numbers.

I tried squaring both sides to eliminate the square roots but the number of terms became too many, making the problem very difficult to handle. I am not really able to understand how to find an easier approach or handle the terms efficiently. Would someone please help me to solve this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's $$\sum_{cyc}\left(x+\frac{1}{x}+2-2\sqrt{2x+1}\right)=0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2-2x\sqrt{2x+1}+2x+1}{x}=0$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x-\sqrt{2x+1})^2}{x}=0,$$
which for $xy<0$ gives infinitely many solutions.

But, for $xy>0$ we obtain:
$$x=\sqrt{2x+1}$$ and $$y=\sqrt{2y+1},$$ which gives 
$$x=y=1+\sqrt2.$$

Comment: Hmm, this is the first time I see the [cyclic sum notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045260/what-does-the-symbol-sum-mathrmcyc-mean)

Comment: How can we show that the individual summands cannot be non-zero ($x = -y$)?

Comment: Thank you Michael!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: @Jan Tojnar  If $y=-x$ we obtain $1=\sqrt{1-4x^2}$ or $x=0,$ which is impossible.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg After sleeping on it, I realized that  such case would be already covered by $xy < 0$.

Comment: @Jan Tojnar Yes, of course. For $xy<0$ there are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 7):

This solution works only for positive $x,y$. However they can not be both negative since then LHS is at most $0$. So $$x+y+ {1\over x}+{1\over y}+4 = x+y+{2x+1\over x}+{2y+1\over y} $$

By Am-Gm we have $$ x+{2x+1\over x}\geq 2\sqrt{x{2x+1\over x}} = 2\sqrt{2x+1}$$ and the same for $y$, so we have

$$x+y+ {1\over x}+{1\over y}+4  \geq 2\sqrt{{2x+1}}+2\sqrt{{2y+1}}$$

Since we have equality is achieved when $x={2x+1\over x}$ (and the same for $y$) we have $x=y=1+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: AM-GM requires terms to be positive. So your solution doesn't account for the case when terms are negative.

Comment: @Maria Mazur Yes, it appears to be wrong as AM-GM only applies to positive real numbers. But still, thanks for providing me with an alternative solution for positive numbers.

Comment: @Maria Mazur After your fixing I deleted my previous comment, Now your statement is true.